# Can't see the controls on the form in design time, runtime is ok

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form and a lot of controls on it, but I can't see these controls in Design time, I mean on *.Designer.cs
The problem has appeared unexpectedly.

Here is my form in runtime:

[image]

And here is the same form in design time:

[image]

So, the question is what should I do to see the form with all controls in *.Designer.cs?
I can't go on with adding / removing components on it using visual designer.

Comment: What is the tab control? Is it out of the box, or some custom user control you're using?

Comment: Tabs are out of the box.

Comment: Hmm... if you Rebuild the solution does it help?

Comment: maybe TabControl, Visible=false?

Comment: @StepUp not relevant, it will still appear in the designer. Something in the internal code got corrupted.

Comment: Could you please explain, how can I detect corruption? Any suggestions? Code to pay attention?

Comment: Is SettingsModel.cs part of the settings.cs construction?

Comment: No, SettingsModel.cs is not a part of the settings.cs construction.

Comment: See the properties in file called "your form.designer.cs". And try to load your TabControl by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have studied the repository carefully and found the reason of the problem I have: somebody has modified **Sps.Tester.Management.csproj** and made it broken. I have added the following lines in it:

```
<Compile Include="Settings.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Settings.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

and the problem has disappeared.